# Calculating the variance of a truncated normally distributed RV given the prob. of a range

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, range

Let's say that I have a Truncated Normal Distribution (from a to b) with mean $m$  (where $m$ is the mean of the truncated Normal) and not known std. I know the probability for the range $m-d$ and $m+d$ (this range is within the truncation points, of course). How do I proceed in calculating the variance of this RV?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say you know the mean $\mu$, is this the mean of the parent random variable $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, or the mean of the truncated Normal (which is something different)

Comment: Is the mean of the truncated random variable

Comment: I have changed the notation to avoid confusion

Comment: Could you also please specify (a) how you know the mean $m$ of the doubly truncated rv (e.g. do you 'know' it from data, or by some formula), and (b) do you know the parameters of the Normal distribution from which the doubly truncated pdf is derived/constructed?

Comment: (a) I know the mean by data. (b) No, I do not. Is it still possible, given these constraints? Thanks

Comment: If you know the sample mean by data, then why don't you just calculate the sample variance from the data?

Comment: What I mean is that I know that one point is the mean. I don't have a sample I  can calculate the mean from.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}$
And $\Phi(y) = P(Y \leq y)$

If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, it is possible to write it as $X = \mu + \sigma Y$ where $Y \sim N(0,1)$

Then, $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma} f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$

Let $Z$ represent the truncated normal bounded between $[a,b]$. Then $f_Z(z)$ is given by:

$$
f_Z(z | a,b) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma} \phi(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})}
$$

It is easy to since the denominator represents the probability of a normal r.v. being in the range $[a,b]$

Now consider the moment generating function(MGF): $M(t)=E[e^{tZ}]$

\begin{align*}
E[e^{tZ}] &=  \frac{1}{\sigma} \frac{1}{\Phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})} \int_a^b  e^{tz}\phi(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma})dz\\
\int_a^b  e^{tz}\phi(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma})dz &= \int_{a}^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{tz}e^{\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_a^b e^{\frac{\sigma^2tz-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_a^b e^{\frac{-\mu^2+(\sigma^2t +\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(z-(\sigma^2t +\mu))^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\mu t + \frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}} \big({\Phi(\frac{z-\mu'}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{a-\mu'}{\sigma})}  \big)
\end{align*}

where $\mu' = \mu+\sigma^2 t$

Use this relation to find $M(t)$. Then:

$var(Z) = M''(t)|_{t=0} - (M'(t)|_{t=0})^2$

Comment: In the comments of the question ... the OP has noted that $\mu$ does not denote the mean of the parent random variable, but rather the mean of the truncated rv.

Answer (score 1):

Given: $X \sim \text{DoublyTruncatedNormal}(a,b)$, constructed from a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ parent, where:

- the bounds $a$ and $b$ are known
- the parent distribution parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are NOT known
- the mean $m$ of $X$ is known (apparently from data)
- the data is NOT available.
- Finally, $P(m-d < X < m+d)$ is known (again, not stated how??), for a given constant $d$.

The question is to find the $\text{Var}(X)$, without the data, knowing only $m= E[X]$ and $P(m-d < X < m+d)$.

A suggested path may be:

1. We know that (see for instance [Wiki Truncated Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)):

$$m = \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}) - \phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}) - \Phi(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma})}$$

This provides one equation with two unknowns ($\mu$ and $\sigma$).

2. It is straightforward to calculate a symbolic expression for  $P(m-d < X < m+d)$, where $d$ is a number. Let $q = P(m-d < X < m+d)$; you assert that $q$ is a known number. This provides a second equation in two unknowns ($\mu$ and $\sigma$).

We thus have two equations in two unknowns, which should be solvable, at least numerically for $\mu$ and $\sigma$. You can then substitute the estimated values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ into the expression for the symbolic expression for $\text{Var}(X)$ which can also be found on the wiki page referenced above.